# Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateException: Convert results are FAILED.:

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, virtuoso, turtle-rdf

I am inserting triples data to graph IRI using SPARQL.

Here is my code,

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Graph;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Triple;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;

import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtGraph;
import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryExecution;
import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory;
import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoUpdateFactory;
import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoUpdateRequest;

public class VirtuosoSPARQLExample9 {

    /**
     * Executes a SPARQL query against a virtuoso url and prints results.
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String url;
        if(args.length == 0)
            url = "jdbc:virtuoso://192.168.99.100:1111";
        else
            url = args[0];

/*          STEP 1          */
        VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph (url, "dba", "dba");

/*          STEP 2          */
                String str = "CLEAR GRAPH <http://192.168.99.100/test1>";
                VirtuosoUpdateRequest vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, set);
                vur.exec();                  

               // InputStream in = new FileInputStream("src/main/webapp/resources/outputfile/test.ttl");


               // Model model1 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(); // creates an in-memory Jena Model
               // model1.read(in, null, "TURTLE");
              //  StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
               // model1.write(out, "TURTLE");
                str = "INSERT INTO GRAPH <http://192.168.99.100/test1> { @base <http://example.org/> .\r\n" + 
                        "@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .\r\n" + 
                        "@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .\r\n" + 
                        "@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .\r\n" + 
                        "@prefix rel: <http://www.perceive.net/schemas/relationship/> .\r\n" + 
                        "\r\n" + 
                        "<#green-goblin>\r\n" + 
                        "    rel:enemyOf <#spiderman> ;\r\n" + 
                        "    a foaf:Person ;    # in the context of the Marvel universe\r\n" + 
                        "    foaf:name \"Green Goblin\" .\r\n" + 
                        "\r\n" + 
                        "<#spiderman>\r\n" + 
                        "    rel:enemyOf <#green-goblin> ;\r\n" + 
                        "    a foaf:Person ;\r\n" + 
                        "    foaf:name \"Spiderman\", \"Человек-паук\"@ru . };";
                vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, set);
                vur.exec();                  


/*      Select all data in virtuoso */
        Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("SELECT * FROM <http://test1> WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }");
        VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, set);
        ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
                System.out.println("\nSELECT results:");
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution rs = results.nextSolution();
            RDFNode s = rs.get("s");
            RDFNode p = rs.get("p");
            RDFNode o = rs.get("o");
            System.out.println(" { " + s + " " + p + " " + o + " . }");
        }

        sparql = QueryFactory.create("DESCRIBE <http://aa> FROM <http://test1>");
        vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, set);

        Model model = vqe.execDescribe();
            Graph g = model.getGraph();
                System.out.println("\nDESCRIBE results:");
            for (Iterator i = g.find(Node.ANY, Node.ANY, Node.ANY); i.hasNext();) 
               {
                  Triple t = (Triple)i.next();
              System.out.println(" { " + t.getSubject() + " " + 
                             t.getPredicate() + " " + 
                             t.getObject() + " . }");
            }



        sparql = QueryFactory.create("CONSTRUCT { ?x <http://test> ?y } FROM <http://test1> WHERE { ?x <http://bb> ?y }");
        vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, set);

        model = vqe.execConstruct();
            g = model.getGraph();
                System.out.println("\nCONSTRUCT results:");
            for (Iterator i = g.find(Node.ANY, Node.ANY, Node.ANY); i.hasNext();) 
               {
                  Triple t = (Triple)i.next();
              System.out.println(" { " + t.getSubject() + " " + 
                             t.getPredicate() + " " + 
                             t.getObject() + " . }");
            }


        sparql = QueryFactory.create("ASK FROM <http://test1> WHERE { <http://aa> <http://bb> ?y }");
        vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, set);

        boolean res = vqe.execAsk();
                System.out.println("\nASK results: "+res);


    }
}
```

While running the query I am getting an error,

```
at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoUpdateRequest.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.bordercloud.sparql.virtuoso.VirtuosoSPARQLExample9.main(VirtuosoSPARQLExample9.java:70)
Caused by: virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoException: SQ074: Line 16: SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 2: syntax error at '@base' before '<http://example.org/>'
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoResultSet.process_result(Unknown Source)
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoResultSet.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoStatement.sendQuery(Unknown Source)
    at virtuoso.jdbc3.VirtuosoStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I am using the virtuoso Jena example while I run the sample example which given on link [Viruoso Jena example](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaSPARQLExample9) it will run perfectly with no error.while I added my `rdf triples data` as an example which having prefix in it won't running perfectly and I am getting the error.

Also, give me hint if any way to load the RDF data file (test.ttl) as directly to the virtuoso server using SPARQL query that will be very useful for me.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: MayI ask you whyyou put a whole Turtle file inside the `INSERT` part of a SPARQL 1.1 Update request? base and prefixes declarations belong to the query, thus, have to be in the beginning of the whole query.

Comment: `com.hp.hpl.jena` - Jena2, not Jena3.

Comment: Hi, @AKSW thanks for the reply.As I need to `INSERT` the Turtle file into the virtuoso server as per requirements so I have tried all the way to Insert the Turtle file using SPARQL query but didn't find the way yet so I have first read that from Turtle file and then Try to `INSERT`. If this is not possible then let me know.

Comment: @AKSW or say like I want to upload the Turtle file to virtuoso server which I need to `INSERT` using code.and as I have mentioned on my question link [Viruoso Jena example](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaSPARQLExample9) There is a way to insert triples.so can you please tell me that how do I do that?

Comment: Hi, @AndyS don't understand what you trying to say!!!

Comment: @vimalDev All I said is that you can't add a full Turtle document inside the `INSERT` block. Only the triple patterns must be there, the `prefix` and `base` declarations must be before the `INSERT` at the beginning of the query: `BASE <> PREFIX p1: <> PREFIX p2 <> ... INSERT INTO GRAPH <http://192.168.99.100/test1> { <s> <p> <o> . ... }`

Comment: @AKSW That I understand, but I need to upload a Turtle file so is there any way to do so? It will very helpful for me if you guide me.Thanks for your reply and time.

Comment: `LOAD <file:///path_to_your_file.ttl> INTO GRAPH <http://192.168.99.100/test1>`

Answer (score 0):

Your Jena `INSERT` is failing because SPARQL does not let you `INSERT` {complete content of a Turtle file} when that content includes `@base`, `@prefix`, and various other things.

To your underlying question, as I have answered you elsewhere previously, there are [MANY documented ways to load data into Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert).

To the specific you've asked about here, you *can* use the SPARQL `LOAD` function, *if* the file you want to load is accessible via HTTP or other Virtuoso-supported URI.  [`file:` scheme URIs (as @AKSW shows) are supported](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert#Using%20the%20file:%20protocol%20specifier) *if* the file is local to the Virtuoso instance -- i.e., if it's on the Virtuoso-local filesystem, not any remote client host -- and *if* the containing directory is included in the value for the [`DirsAllowed` setting of the `[Parameters]` stanza](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/dbadm/#ini_parameters_dirsallowed).

```
LOAD <file:///path_to_your_file.ttl> INTO GRAPH <http://192.168.99.100/test1>
```

I strongly encourage you to [read the documentation](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert). It really does answer a lot of questions.